# Domain level problem for multisite?

Tags: multisite

I want to use multisite for Wordpress. However, my main Wordpress site is on foo.bar.com. I want to add multi-sites like **ex.bar.com**, **ex1.bar.com**.

How can I configure the settings for doing that?

Answer (score 0):

The googles know about tons of tutorials on multisite setup/management. Start here http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-wordpress-multisite-network/ .

(Asking the googles is a good place to start any question. Much knowledge there, although it takes a bit of work to find best resources.)